# How to remove Macrovision Software Updater for good

Tags: windows

I'm having trouble with this "Software Updater" in a couple of windows machines, which has malware-like behaviour. I kill the process, run an "oficial" uninstaller, delete the folders and still it comes back again after reboot.

I don't know really how it got installed, I think it is part of the InstallShield stuff and installed with another software.

It is installed in "Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Macrovision" and I think it installs also on "Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Macrovision".

The processes are named "agent.exe" and "ISUSPM.exe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the file creation dates, I finally tracked the source of the install to a 3G USB modem. So the uninstall method was working well.